# Varnish is working but X-Drupal cache is missed

Tags: 7, caching, performance, proxies

I have [configured](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish.html) varnish on a Digital Ocean server and installed Drupal varnish module. I have confirmed that varnish is running  but once i do a test on my site using [blazemeter.com](http://blazemeter.com) the server CPU goes at 100% during the test duration ( 20 minutes)

```
root@gtdev:~#  curl -SLIXGET http://46.101.217.71/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 09:57:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: ar
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Etag: "1462960672-1"
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 May 2016 09:57:52 GMT
X-Varnish: 373674512
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
```

**Drupal Varnish Module Configuratoin:**

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/varnish/varnish.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'VarnishCache';
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = false;
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = true;
$conf['cache'] = 1;
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 0;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 21600;
$conf['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR';
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1');
$conf['omit_vary_cookie'] = true;
```

[image]

[isvarnishworking.com](http://www.isvarnishworking.com/) says that it is working as "Sort Of". So if its working then why the CPU is on 100% usage any idea ?

Comment: Maybe your CPU is very slow and 100% actually isn't much horsepower at all? It's quite difficult to guess at the problem without access to the servers to debug

Comment: Its 8GB Ram, i am paying 80$ a month to Digital Ocean.

Comment: If i can do some thing to get  some value in "X-Drupal-Cache" and "Age" , it might fix the problem.

Comment: Just noticed the `MISS` so ignore my comment (at least until that becomes a `HIT` and you still see the same CPU spike)

Comment: http://46.101.217.71/test/index.html does not show any miss, it means Drupal has the problem somewhere.

Comment: Not really - if you're seeing a `HIT` from varnish, but the same request is making the CPU spike on a server that was never supposed to be hit in the first place, I'd be more inclined to think Varnish is telling you fibs